# Kapitza oscillator animation too slow and choppy

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I wrote a program to model and plot the kapitza oscillator and as an extra credit i descided to animate it, but the second animation (when the 2nd oscilator is on) is very slow and thus you cant really see whats going on. Is there anything i can do to speed this up? And what is causing it to be slow, is it simply down to computing power, bad optimasation or is there some parameter i can add to tell it to go faster. This is my first time animating anything in python so im not very familiar at all with it. Heres the code:

```
    # Kapitza oscillator

import numpy as np
from solvers import rk4
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def g(t, X):
    def A(t):
        return A0 * np.sin(100 * omega0 * t)

    theta, omega = X
    thetaDot = omega
    omegaDot = A(t) * np.sin(theta) - gamma * omega - (omega0 ** 2) * np.sin(theta)
    Xdot = np.array([thetaDot, omegaDot])
    return Xdot


gamma, omega0 = 1, (2 * np.pi)
X0 = np.array([0.9 * np.pi, 0])

A0 = 0
solver2a = rk4(g, X0, 0.001)

ts2a = []
Xsa = []
for t, X in solver2a:
    ts2a.append(t)
    Xsa.append(X)
    if t > 20:
        break

A0 = 10 ** 4
solver2b = rk4(g, X0, 1e-4)

ts2b = []
Xsb = []
for t, X in solver2b:
    ts2b.append(t)
    Xsb.append(X)
    if t > 20:
        break

Xsa = np.array(Xsa)
Xsb = np.array(Xsb)

plt.plot(ts2a, Xsa[:, 0], label='Angular displacement for fixed A')
plt.plot(ts2b, Xsb[:, 0], label='Angular displacement for A0=10e4')
plt.legend()

#EXTRA: Tried making animations for the oscilators (only work with Qt5 graphics backbone).
#The method I used seems to be rather slow to show the kapitza oscillator as smoothly as i would like 
x = ts2a
y = Xsa[:,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y)

def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    line.axes.axis([0, 20, -2, 3])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line], interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()

x = ts2b
y = Xsb[:,0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y)

def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    line.axes.axis([0, 20, -1, 3.75])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line], interval=1e-10, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

note that im using runge kutta 4 (rk4) from external solvers saved on my computer that were provided by my lecturer. Here is the code for that:

```
def rk4(f, x0, dt):
    tn = 0
    xn = x0

    while True:        
        yield tn,xn

        k1 = dt*f(tn,xn)
        k2 = dt*f(tn+dt/2,xn+k1/2)
        k3 = dt*f(tn+dt/2,xn+k2/2)
        k4 = dt*f(tn+dt,xn+k3)

        xn = xn + (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
        tn = tn + dt
```

Comment: If `solvers` is required for this problem, you need to ask your lecturer for help. If you want to ask people on the internet for help you need to provide them with a [mcve].

Comment: i mean i dont think that will effect the animation, my problem isnt with that part of the code, runge kutta is a pretty well known method i though, but i shall add that bit of code now.

Comment: Have you tried to profile the code execution?

Comment: It's not actually that slow. It's just lots of data (20000) points. If you only plot every 10th point, you will loose no resolution, but the animation will be able to cope with the data lot.

Comment: how would i go about doing that? I thought thats what interval did in FuncAnimation but changing that seems to have no effect on the speed of the animation.

Answer (score 1):

By considering only every tenth element of x and y by

```
x = x[::10]
y = y[::10]
```

it runs much faster for me, but is still not very smooth. Do you have to show the animation at run time? If not, you could save it as MP4

```
ani.save('animation.mp4', fps=15)
```

which actually does run very smoothly. So the choppy run time animation is maybe due to performance issues.

**EDIT:** I managed to get it working smoothly by changing the interval (delay between frames in ms) to 20 instead of 1. This also seems to be a more reasonable value for an animation (the interval=1 would correspond to 1000 FPS).

Comment: Thank you so much man, yeah this worked a treat. I'm still trying to learn everything that goes into animating plots with matplotlib so this helps a lot. Cheers.